# Defer updating knockoutjs model until validation / save

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to create a custom event for valueUpdate so that I can 
defer updating my model until an object has been validated/saved?

The [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#!s!valueUpdate) says:

> The following string values are the most commonly useful choices:
>
> "change"..., "keyup"..., "keypress"..., "afterkeydown"...

implying that other values are possible, but not stating where I might find a full list.

I want to have a pop-up form (in a hidden div until needed) with a cancel button that causes the form to be deleted without updating the model. The model should only be updated when the user presses the save button.

(I've slightly copied this question from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/knockoutjs/UWwsTQrQfZ0) - it seems I'm not the only one who wants this, but they had got no answer)

Comment: I understand the issue that you are having with the change event. However, I wanted to suggest an alternative pattern where you use a structure that allows you to explicity commit the value like: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer IMHO, that should be an answer not a comment :-) It's a very good pattern that probably has further use cases (that doesn't mean that being able to disable change events wouldn't still be a good thing)

Comment: @RPNiemeyer is there any way to get the mapping plugin (https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/knockout.mapping.js) to generate protectedObservables rather than normal observables by default?

Comment: You have to use the `create` callbacks (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing_object_construction_using_create) in the mapping plugin to customzie object creation.  There is not a way to make it create the protectedObservables by default without replacing observables with protectedObservables at run-time in ko.

Comment: There is definitely a lot you can do with structures like the protectedObseravble.  It is easy to add other features like adding a `peek` method to be able to get at the temp value or adding undo/redo type functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is the option to subscribe to the 'beforeChange' notification stream from an observable.
This gives you the chance to inspect the value before it changes.

The most obvious way to really tackle model validation is to use 'writable' compute values.
These allow you to incorporate your validation logic

Comment: Blocking the update at the beforeChange method, so that I can then allow it later when the user want's to press save seems like a pretty hacky way to do it, particularly as I'll want to block changes form this form element, but not from an update received from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what the documentation implies, the `valueUpdate` parameter does not "define which browser event KO should use to detect changes" with the default being "change", it allows you to supply an event or list of possible events that should be caught in addition to "change" which is always caught.

The relevant [code](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings.js#L121) is:

```
// Always catch "change" event; possibly other events too if asked
var eventsToCatch = ["change"];
var requestedEventsToCatch = allBindingsAccessor()["valueUpdate"];
if (requestedEventsToCatch) {
    if (typeof requestedEventsToCatch == "string") // Allow both individual event names, and arrays of event names
        requestedEventsToCatch = [requestedEventsToCatch];
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(eventsToCatch, requestedEventsToCatch);
    eventsToCatch = ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(eventsToCatch);
}
```

This behaviour was actually requested and implimented in: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/102
https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/commit/843420a6f801b17dd357880b359a67fa53647999

It looks like the docs have not been updated. I'd prefer people to have to request change if they want it, and the docs to tell them something like:

"list of events, we recommend including 'change', pass [] to disable automatically updating the model"